# Map SELinux requested permission to string representing System Call

Tags: selinux, libselinux, seandroid

I am trying to map the `requested` access control vector to the corresponding textual representation of the system call in the following function:

```
int avc_has_perm(security_id_t ssid, security_id_t tsid,
         security_class_t tclass, access_vector_t requested,
         struct avc_entry_ref *aeref, void *auditdata)
```

From the documentation I can see that:

```
requested = requested permissions, interpreted based on @tclass
```

Is there a function that maps such `requested` field to the textual representation of the associated system call (i.e., read, write, open, etc.)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the mapping is done at the kernel space by using the `secclass_map[]` structure declared inside the `./security/selinux/include/classmap.h`.

A function that shows how to do the mapping is  avc_dump_av inside `./security/selinux/avc.c`